# What will happen when an ethereum node loss internet connection?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, synchronization, contract-invocation

1. Will it reconnect to the ethereum network upon establishing internet connection again automatically and sync Data ?
2. Can we perform transaction and calls on the offline(no internet connection) ethereum node specifically ? suppose we have direct access to that particaular node and we can directly intereact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- once reconnected your node will continue syncing data (downloading the missing blocks)

2- you can [create a transaction offline](https://tokenmarket.net/blog/creating-offline-ethereum-transactions-in-javascript/) and sign it then broadcast it later when the internet comes back. you may use this offline node to call a constant function (if it has a synced version of the blockchain) and get back the calculation result.

Comment: if a smart contract which is already deployed on the blockchain network and is currently available on the offline node, can we interact with it such as perform transaction and get data from the local copy of the blockchain.